# JSQMessagesViewController add button to bubble

Tags: xamarin.ios, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

i use this nuget   https://www.nuget.org/packages/JSQMessagesViewController
 to provide binding on my xamarin ios project.

Question is how to add custom cell to JSQMessagesViewController that it includes one view with some button?[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvnaW.png)

i find solution on this issue https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/1739#issuecomment-246489889
    but have trouble convert swift to c# code

Comment: You link to a binary that has no documentation and is marked as deprecated, and expect answers?

Comment: I hope that someone decides this case give answer

Comment: @AlexHeal I tried to convert it to c#, even though the buttons show on the screen but the effect seems not well without bubble around it. Also I find the oc project may also have this issues. I recommend you to change another plugin.

Comment: Thank you, someday i try goth this using https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit